# Upload the newest file, in the newest folder, to FTP server

Tags: batch-file, ftp, winscp

I am running a task with Window task scheduler and WinSCP. Basically what I want to do is upload the newest file, everyday at 1pm (which is done in task scheduler), the problem is every day a new folder is created in `F:\Satellite_Imagery\goes16\fd\NOMAP\todays` date (`2020-05-12`, `2020-05-13`, etc.) How can I get the script to automatically find the newest folder and then the newest file in that folder?

This is the task code I have running (without a method for finding the newest folder)

```
/log="C:\Users\Myuser\Documents\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul /command "open ftp://Username:password@ftp.myftpsite.com" "put -latest F:\Satellite_Imagery\goes16\fd\NOMAP\2020-05-12\*  /public_html/GOES16DATA/" "mv public_html/GOES16DATA/GOES*.jpg public_html/GOES16DATA/goestoday.jpg" "exit"
```

Answer (score 1):

With WinSCP scripting, you can upload the latest file in a given folder (what you are doing now), or the latest folder. But not the latest file in the latest folder.

---

Though, if you know that the folder name is today, you can use [`%TIMESTAMP% syntax`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp) to identify that folder (and then the [`-latest` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#latest) to find the latest file in that folder):

```
"put -latest F:\Satellite_Imagery\goes16\fd\NOMAP\%%TIMESTAMP#yyyy-mm-dd%%\*  /public_html/GOES16DATA/"
```

---

If you really need to find the latest folder, you will have to use a more powerful language. You can use [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) from e.g. [PowerShell script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell).

You can start based on this article:
[Uploading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_most_recent_file). You will just have to repeat the selection code (`Get-ChildItem` ... `Sort-Object` ... `Select-Object`) for both levels.